# Obtener un porcentaje de registro [actualizado]

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando obtener un porcentaje de registros de usuarios para un plataforma de ventas, en comparación con el mes anterior y no sé como tomar la base del cálculo para lograrlo, quizás en mas simple de lo que creo, pero no puedo resolverlo.

Debería obtener algo así: `+20%` ó `-10%` ó `=` de registro en comparación al mes pasado.

> **Actualización**: en las últimas líneas hice los cálculos en una regla de 3 simple para obtener los porcentajes, pero no logro reemplazar los valores que vienen de la base de datos.

tabla usuarios

```
| id | nombre | fecha      |
----------------------------
| 1  | pedro  | 2022-08-19 |
| 2  | mario  | 2022-08-21 |
| 3  | luis   | 2022-09-09 |
| 4  | ana    | 2022-09-15 |
| 5  | maria  | 2022-10-03 |
| 6  | laura  | 2022-10-12 |
| 7  | miguel | 2022-10-16 |
```

porcentaje.php

```
<?php

$app = new Main();

// tomo el mes de la fecha de registro y agrupo, cuento los usuarios desde el id que se registraron el mismo mes
$sql = $app->connect()->query("SELECT MONTH(fecha) month, COUNT(id) id FROM usuarios GROUP BY MONTH (fecha) ORDER BY MONTH (fecha)");
$ress = $sql->fetchAll();

// obtengo el mes anterior al actual
$mes_anterior = date('m', strtotime('-1 month'));
echo 'mes anterior: '.$mes_anterior;

echo "<hr>";

// listo los usuarios registrados por cada mes
foreach($ress as $row){
    echo 'usuarios registrados en el mes '.$row['month'].': '.$row['id'].'<br>';
}

echo "<hr>";

// obtengo el mes actual
$fecha = '2022-10-16';
$fecha_str = strtotime($fecha);
$mes = date("m", $fecha_str);
echo 'mes actual: '.$mes;

echo "<hr>";

$a = 12; // total mes pasado
$b = 8; // total mes actual

$p_total = 100; //

$p = $b * 100 / $a - 100;
if($p > 0){
    echo '+'.round($p, 2).'%';
} elseif($p < 0){
    echo round($p, 2).'%';
} elseif($p == 0){
    echo '=';
}

?>
```

Agradezco la ayuda de antemano

Comment: Supongo que el problema no es de PHP o codificación, sino de pura matemática.  Prueba con `(($b/$a)*100)-100`  ([en este enlace](https://www.disfrutalasmatematicas.com/numeros/porcentaje-diferencia.html) te muestran dos métodos, este sería el segundo)

Comment: Gracias masterguru, eso ya lo pude resolver, lo que estoy intentando resolver ahora es trasladas los datos que vienen desde la base de datos. En la variable `$a` puedo obtener el valor del mes anterior, pero en la variable `$b` no logro obtenerlo

Comment: No se si te refieres a poner esto dentro del **foreach**:  `$meses[$row['month']] = $row['id'];`  para luego, ya fuera del bucle, conseguir los datos del mes con `$meses['10']`  (mes actual Octubre) o cualquier otro mes que haya devuelto cambiando el 10 por el número de mes que desees saber... ¿es eso donde te has encallado?

Comment: Claro, así después puedo reemplazar los valores... voy a probarlo